For INA2xx power sensors (INA226 specificly) may I use resistive divider for more voltage
I need to use this INA 2xx power sensors on a project with ESP32. But I have a bus voltage more than 36V (which is the max limit of INA226), there is a INA238 for 85 V which is is enough for my project.
But the thing is there is literally no code source (library) on the web for ina238 but there are lots of libraries for INA226. So I am planning to use a basic voltage division (like 1 to 3) with resistors to have a bus voltage less than the max limit of INA226 and then multiply it by three in the software. Is this a logical solution for this problem? It should be basic and simple as that right just I will divide my real Vbus and feed it like a fake Vbus to the sensor, all other connections and logic should be the same.

Are you using a high-side or low-side shunt resistor to measure the load current?

If you use a low-side sensing current, it "seems" that you can use a 1/4 divider for Vbus. Note that I did not try this.

yes, but you would need separate sensors for voltage and current; low-side current and high-side resistor-divided voltage. can you use a multi-channel ADC and a shunt instead?

@JonathanS.
I didn't quite get the problem of low side and high side to be honest. I would just measure the divided voltage and planning to multiply it from the software and use the normal current measurement
